# Как получить id последнего элемента?

Tags: xml, php

```
<Sites>
    <Items>
        <Item>
            <id>1</id>
            <URL>https://mysite.com</URL>
            <Host>mysite.com</Host>
            <Folder>mysite</Folder>
            <Database>mysite_app</Database>
            <DBuser>mysite_app</DBuser>
            <DBpassword>pass</DBpassword>
        </Item>
        <Item>
            <id>2</id>
            <URL>https://mysite.com</URL>
            <Host>mysite.com</Host>
            <Folder>mysite</Folder>
            <Database>mysite_app</Database>
            <DBuser>mysite_app</DBuser>
            <DBpassword>pass</DBpassword>
        </Item>
    </Items>
</Sites>
```

Нужно получить id последнего элемента Item. Подскажите, как это можно реализовать.

Comment: В XQuery это просто: (/sites/items/item)[last()]/@id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В переменной $xml - ваш XML-код. [Проверяем работу](http://ideone.com/HhEAo7)

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($xml);
$items = $doc->getElementsByTagName('id');
echo $items->item($items->length - 1)->nodeValue; // 2
```

Comment: Дело в том, что id могут идти не по порядку. Например, был удалён сайт с id=5, и id будут равны 1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, и данный код вернёт 6, в то время как в действительности это 7.

Comment: @Ford, вас не смущает, что в заголовке написано именно

> получить последний id

?

В любом случае можно и догадаться, что вышеописанная конструкция легко поддается итерации.

Comment: @Ford, можете показать пример такого "неупорядоченного" кода? Потому что проблемы я не вижу, т.к. мы обращаемся к элементу по его индексу, и о каком порядке вы говорите, я не понимаю.

Comment: А если у последнего item будет subitem со своим id?